# Bash script output differs when re-directed directly and run by cron

Tags: bash, cron

I have written the following Bash script

```
TIME=$( date '+%F %H:%M:%S')
MYRUNLEVEL=$(runlevel | cut -d ' ' -f2)

printf "Script started  successfully at  $TIME"
printf ",    Runlevel is $MYRUNLEVEL"
printf "\n"
```

When I run the cript from my terminal, like this

```
$ backup_script.sh >> test_output.txt
$ cat test_output.txt 
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:53:19,    Runlevel is 5
```

I get the runlevel correctly written out.
But when I run the script from a cronjob the runlevel is not written out:

Crontab syntax:

```
 * * * * * /home/philip//bin/backup_script.sh >> /home/philip/LinuxMint/Test_script/cron_output
```

Output in the file cron_output:

```
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:48:01,    Runlevel is
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:49:01,    Runlevel is
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:50:01,    Runlevel is
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:51:01,    Runlevel is
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:52:01,    Runlevel is
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:53:01,    Runlevel is
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:54:01,    Runlevel is
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:55:01,    Runlevel is
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-12 14:56:02,    Runlevel is
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `cut -d ' ' -f2` in `MYRUNLEVEL=$(runlevel | cut -d ' ' -f2)` is making the output empty. Try to use just `MYRUNLEVEL="$(runlevel)"` and see if you get what you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

Running the script as a cronjob did not find the runlevel command. By adding the full path to runlevel solved the problem

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=$( date '+%F %H:%M:%S')
MYRUNLEVEL=$(/sbin/runlevel | cut -d ' ' -f2)

printf "Script started  successfully at  $TIME"
printf ",    Runlevel is $MYRUNLEVEL "
```

crontab syntax:

```
* * * * * /home/philip//bin/backup_script.sh >> /home/philip/LinuxMint/Test_script/cron_output
```

gives output in cron_output:

```
Script started  successfully at  2020-04-13 16:04:01,    Runlevel is 5
```